# Honeypot for Linux user

Tags: linux, honeypot

Let's consider the following scenario:
You have a web -facing server, which runs software e.g. `apache2` on separate Linux user `www-data`. An attacker finds a vulnerability and gets a remote shell on your system with privileges of `www-data` user.

Is it possible to have honeypot on commands run by the `www-data` user? For example, let's assume that `apache2` or any other process run by `www-data`, never runs `ls` command to list directory (it would most likely use other API provided by the system, rather than start new process parse output etc). Is it possible to set-up a honeypot on such command? For example, log the commands in sys.log, or add an entry to a database with only `INSERT` permission?

The command should still run normally on other users (or specified) accounts, without triggering the log event.

If such honeypot is possible, how could one be set up?
Is there any reasons why such honeypot is bad and should not be used?

Comment: Why would you want a honeypot once they have full control over the process and local control? Isn't it far too late?

Comment: Well I was thinking of this a bit more as of "you been hacked" flag. In some cases compromised services / users can go for long time without being noticed by administrator, but adding such custom behaviour potentially could help finding it out sooner and reducing the impact

Comment: Then you don't want a honeypot. You want a tripwire. You want to be alerted when certain commands are run. That's a different problem.

Comment: Are you also aware of things like: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/155139/does-usr-sbin-nologin-as-a-login-shell-serve-a-security-purpose

Comment: I have read the link you have provided, however there still are sometimes cases where commands can be executed without system shell, e.g. php's `shell_exec`. Similarly any program can spawn new processes, pretty much ignoring the setting mentioned in /etc/passwd

Comment: You are not going to be able to reach all those places to capture and log all possible methods of running commands.

Comment: While something like [Tripwire](https://www.tecmint.com/install-tripwire-ids-intrusion-detection-system-on-linux/) might be easier to setup as an IDS, which based off comments _almost sounds_ like part of what you are looking for... that wouldn't cover processes spawning processes, [strace](https://strace.io) with some kind of profiling could be bodged together... What's your experience with containers, eg. `chroot`, `firejail`, `docker`? I ask because it may be easier to make a custom FS for your service, and replace anything it doesn't need with a script that trips your "hacked" _flag_.

Comment: @S0AndS0 i never used any containers yet but dont feel that this is limiting factor, as i am willing to learn them

Comment: Okay, I'll keep it in mind while I try to sketch-out the shape of the monster I believe you are wishing for... I'm more of a [`chroot`](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/unix-linux-chroot-command-examples-usage-syntax/) and [`firejail`](https://firejail.wordpress.com/documentation-2/seccomp-guide/) kinda person but will admit that [`docker`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/seccomp/) could be a _better_ fit for automation. Automation of various tools is one of the things that seems to be _key_ for collecting higher quality data, though is fraught with opportunities for frustration.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you want to have a custom shell environment for this one user. Replace `bash` with a custom variant that only allows certain commands and logs the other commands.

Kippo/Cowrie would be a good model for you to look at for creating something like this and all the challenges and limitations, as well. Kippo/Cowrie is for faking ssh shells.

Comment: Some friends and I once wrote a program called "honeydoor". It is both a backdoor shell and a honeypot in one c program. If you log in as the 'doored' user, you get a bash shell. If you log in with one of programmed commonly used telnet password combos like 'root:toor', than you get the fake shell, which logs all commands. After a certain # of failed attempts it just spits urandom data at you (hopefully crashing the scanner) This is a pretty fun way to collect default logins and payloads, and is easier to set up than kippo:   
https://gist.github.com/darkerego/9771c474e73852986cacea3ee13f2096